# Why does my image always appear behind another image in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just started Unity (following a course from Udemy). I've run into this issue where any object/image I add is always added behind my background...

I'm not sure how to fix it so the spaceship (seen extending past the background) is in-front of the background...

I've tried playing with the layers, but that didn't work...

[image: https://i.imgur.com/epUswrD.png]

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Do you have some code that causes this?

Comment: @UnholySheep My bad, it was suggested. Removed.

Answer (score 1):

It was because my Galaxy had a z index... So the camera was placed in between the the player and galaxy. Setting the z to 0 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

z value of position and hierarchy position both can be the issue.
Also you can give it sortingLayer :)